# Difference between at symbol (@) vs colon (:) for parameter assignment in postgres/npgsql

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

I'm trying to search for this, but with symbols it's just about impossible to get results. Is there a difference between these two, e.g. being put into a query string in C#:

```
string strCmd = "SELECT * FROM MyFunction(@user_id, @action_date)"
```

vs

```
string strCmd = "SELECT * FROM MyFunction(:user_id, :action_date)"
```

I've always used colons, but I occasionally see it done the other way. I'd like to know if they're interchangeable or when one or the other is preferred.

Comment: I've never seen it done with colons before aside from when used in psql i.e. completely unrelated to npgsql functionality

Answer (score 4):

There's no difference whatsoever between the two characters: both are parameter placeholders. Note that these aren't actually sent to PostgreSQL; Npgsql rewrites the SQL query, replacing them client-side with PostgreSQL's positional parameter placeholder ($1, $2).