# Meaning of the character @ in psql

Tags: postgresql, psql

I found the next psql command:

```
CREATE TABLE @cdmDatabaseSchema.PERSON (
            person_id integer NOT NULL,
            gender_concept_id integer NOT NULL,
            year_of_birth integer NOT NULL,
            month_of_birth integer NULL,
            day_of_birth integer NULL,
            birth_datetime TIMESTAMP NULL,
            race_concept_id integer NOT NULL,
            ethnicity_concept_id integer NOT NULL,
            location_id integer NULL,
            provider_id integer NULL,
            care_site_id integer NULL,
            person_source_value varchar(50) NULL,
            gender_source_value varchar(50) NULL,
            gender_source_concept_id integer NULL,
            race_source_value varchar(50) NULL,
            race_source_concept_id integer NULL,
            ethnicity_source_value varchar(50) NULL,
            ethnicity_source_concept_id integer NULL );
```

What is the symbol @ located just after CREATE TABLE for? Is there any special meaning/advantage to its use?

Comment: That's invalid SQL and won't run without change. Maybe the `@cdmDatabaseSchema` is replaced by some tool _before_ that is executed.

Comment: I agree, it looks like it could be a formatting symbol (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49542854/difference-between-at-symbol-vs-colon-for-parameter-assignment-in-postgr).

Comment: What tool could take advantage of the @ character? I saw other table definitions using the same @. Could this be a parameter for a psql file? I mean, could  @cdmDatabaseSchema  be a parameter? if so, how to call this parameter?